# How to update the values using NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter, api, textfield

I created a user profile screen, where user can also edit the fields by clicking on edit button, it will appear a popup dialogue where i display the fields which are allowed to edit. And I am using API which i create it using NodeJS to update that fields, it is working, values are updating.

**Problem:**

There are 5 fields in edit dialogue box (email, phoneNo, address, education and martialstatus), but if user only want to edit the education field, and want rest field remain same, and when user click on update change button where i call the api, it only update the that field which is edited and update the other field to `null`, because it gets null value from the field controller (i am passing the textfield controller to api body parameter).

**Solution which i think:**

It can be done using conditions (if-else) to handle the `null` value, by passing the old values which i am getting using shared preference, but it will be not efficient, because there are 5 fields yet, but if in future if edit fields number increase, then more condition (checks) will be needed.

**here is backend api code:**

```
updateprofile = (req,res)=>{
  
  jwt.verify(req.body.token, 'secret' , function(err, decoded) {
    if(err) {
     err["expiredAt"] = err["expiredAt"].toLocaleString();
     res.status(300).json(err)
    }
    else
      {
  User.find({"username":req.body.username,_id: req.body.id},function(err,data){
    console.log(req.body)

    User.updateOne({"username":req.body.username, _id: req.body.id}, {"email":req.body.email,"education":req.body.education,"PhoneNo":req.body.PhoneNo,"address":req.body.address,"martialstatus":req.body.martialstatus},function(err,dat){
      if(err)   
        res.json("You Last login Yesterday");
      else  
        {
          var token = jwt.sign({
            data: 'foobar'
     }, 'secret', { expiresIn: "30 minute"})
     
    res.status(200).json({auth: true, AccessToken: token,email:req.body.email,education:req.body.education,phone:req.body.PhoneNo,address:req.body.address,martialstatus:req.body.martialstatus})
        }
        })}) 
}})}
```

**here is edit dialogue and shared preference code:**

```
String getname="";
  String getemail="";
  String getdesignation="";
  String getType="";
  String getId="";
  String getToken="";
  String getEducation="";
  String getPhone="";
  String getMartialStatus="";
  String getAddress="";
  String getDob="";

 _userDetails() async{
    SharedPreferences myPrefs=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      getname=myPrefs.getString('name'); 
      getemail=myPrefs.getString('email'); 
      getdesignation=myPrefs.getString('designation');     
      getType=myPrefs.getString('type');
      getId=myPrefs.getString('UserId');
      getToken=myPrefs.getString('accesstoken');
      getPhone=myPrefs.getString('phone');
      getEducation=myPrefs.getString('education');
      getMartialStatus=myPrefs.getString('martialstatus');
      getAddress=myPrefs.get('address');
      getDob=myPrefs.get('DOB');
         
    }); 
   }


 _displayTextInputDialog(BuildContext context)  {
   return showDialog(
       context: context,
       builder: (context) {
         return 
         Center(child: 
         Column(children: <Widget>[
          AlertDialog(
           title: Text('Profile Edit'),
           content: Column(children: <Widget>[
             TextField(
             
             onChanged: (value) {
               setState(() {
                 valueText = value;
               });
             },
             controller: email,
             decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: getemail,icon: Icon(Icons.email)),
           ),
            TextField(
             
             onChanged: (value) {
               setState(() {
                 valueText = value;
               });
             },
             controller: phone,
             decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: getPhone,icon: Icon(Icons.phone)),
           ),
           TextField(
             
             onChanged: (value) {
               setState(() {
                 valueText = value;
               });
             },
             controller: address,
             decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: getAddress,icon: Icon(Icons.location_on)),
           ),
           TextField(
             
             onChanged: (value) {
               setState(() {
                 valueText = value;
               });
             },
             controller: education,
             decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: getEducation,icon: Icon(Icons.library_books)),
           ),
           TextField(
             
             onChanged: (value) {
               setState(() {
                 valueText = value;
               });
             },
             controller: martialstatus,
             decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: getMartialStatus,icon: Icon(Icons.group)
           ),
           )],),
           
           actions: <Widget>[
             FlatButton(
               color: Colors.green,
               textColor: Colors.white,
               child: Text('Update Changes'),
               onPressed: () {
                 setState(() {
                   valuebutton = valueText;
                   updateProfile();  //here calling the api function to udpate the values
                   Navigator.pop(context);
                 });
               },
             ),
  
         ],)
        
           ],
         ));
       });
 }
```

**here i'm using api and calling the function on update changes button**

```
Dio dio = new Dio();
  var data={};
  
  Future updateProfile() async {
    try{
      var data={

        "username":getname,
        "id":getId,
        "token":getToken,
        "email":email.text,
        "PhoneNo":phone.text,
        "martialstatus":martialstatus.text,
        "address":address.text,
        "education":education.text

      }; dio
            .post(localHostUrlUpdateProfile, data: json.encode(data))
              .then((onResponse) async {
               
                showDialog(context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context){
                  return AdvanceCustomAlert(
                  title: "Profile Updated",
                  descriptions:"Profile is updated successfully!",icon: Icons.check,
                  bgcolor: Colors.green,
                  fgcolor: Colors.green,);
                  }
                );
    });}
    catch (e) {
      print("error");
      bool checkStatus =
          OSError.noErrorCode == 113 || OSError.noErrorCode == 101;
      print(checkStatus);
      print(OSError.noErrorCode == 113);
      
      if (e is DioError) {
        print(e.response);
      }
      if (checkStatus == false) {
        print("con er");
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AdvanceCustomAlert(
                title: "Connection Error",
                descriptions: "An unknown network error occured.",
                icon: Icons.error,
                bgcolor: Colors.red,
                fgcolor: Colors.red,
              );
            });
      }
    }

  }
```

hope all clear, please help if anyone know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

i just reduced the condition logic to this

```
if(email.text==""){
          email.text=getemail;
      }
      if(phone.text==""){
        phone.text=getPhone;
      }
        education.text=getEducation;
      }
      if(address.text==""){
        address.text=getAddress;
      }
      if(martialstatus.text==""){
        martialstatus.text=getMartialStatus;
      }
```

it is working, would appreciate if someone know the better solution than this.